# Java string indexing make me confused

Tags: java

So i need to gather data from my db, it's holiday date in my country, the data comes like this

```
Example 1 : THU     21    May     Ascension Day of Jesus Christ        *ICDX GOLD open for
Example 2 : MON-THU 28-31 Dec     Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival
```

So i need to get data from days, dates, and the holiday name, for get data from example 1 i'm using code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ex1 = "THU     21    May     Ascension Day of Jesus Christ        *ICDX GOLD open for";
    String ex2 = "MON-THU 28-31 Dec     Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival       ";
    String[] trim1 = ex1.trim().split("\\s+"); //to split by space
    String[] trim2 = ex1.trim().split("   "); //to split by 3 space so i got the data from multiple space as delimiter

    System.out.println("DAY " +trim1[0]);//display day
    System.out.println("DATE " +trim1[1] +trim1[2]+"2020");//display date
    System.out.println("HOLIDAY NAME " +trim2[3]);//dispay holiday name

}
```

The Output come like this

`DAY MON 
 DATE 21May2020
 HOLIDAY NAME Ascension Day of Jesus Christ`

and just like what i need, but when come to example 2, i can't use same code because the space is different, how to get the data i need with example 1 and 2 with same code.

i am new in java so i'm sorry if my question looking dumb, i hope you can help me.Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that both your examples have all respective data starting at a certain position. Can't you extract your data based on that?

Comment: Is it normal that you use `ex1.trim()` for `trim1` and `trim2`? The variable `ex2` isn't used.

Comment: hey guys, i already solve this problem, thank for all the help, but i have new problem xD i post new thread about it, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

`.split("\\s+")` will split at any space, including multiple spaces. Eg. it will split at 1 space or more.

This means that you are able to split at any amount of spaces (what you want). However, this will also split your text comments. You are able to limit the length of the array produced (the amount of times it is split) using .split(regex, n), which will result in an array of n-1 size at most. [See this for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

As for splitting out your two textual comments, I cannot see a way to do this.

`Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival       ";` contains no way of telling what is the first text comment and the second.

It seems quite strange to me that you receive information from your database like this, I would recommend seeing if there are other options for doing this. There is almost certainly a way to get seperate fields.

If have the ability to change all the information in the database, you could put single quotes (') or some other seperator, which you would then be able to split out the two pieces of text.

Comment: from you i got idea, thanks i already solve this problem with your help, but i got another one hehe, so i ask once again in this lovely community, thanks for your help sir :D

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what @DanielBarbarian suggested: Since the information seems to always start at the same indexes, you can just use those to get what you need.

```
String ex1 = "THU     21    May     Ascension Day of Jesus Christ        *ICDX GOLD open for";
String ex2 = "MON-THU 28-31 Dec     Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival       ";

String day = ex2.substring(0, 8).trim();
String date = ex2.substring(8, 14).trim() + ex2.substring(14, 22).trim() + "2020";
String name = ex2.substring(22);

System.out.println("DAY " + day);// display day
System.out.println("DATE " + date);// display date
System.out.println("HOLIDAY NAME " + name);// dispay holiday name
```